# Unable to locate element (error selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-extraction

I'm making a web scraper script in python and I need to navigate between pages. All good 'till page # 4, but when it's in the last one I get the following error:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class="pagination"]/li/span[@onclick="GoToPage(5)"]"}

This is my code:

```py
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def main():
    url = "https://offcampus.uwo.ca/listings/"

    os.environ['PATH'] += r"D:/Usuario/Desktop/web_s"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get(url)

    for k in range(1, 6):
        print(f'page # {k}')
        address = driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, '//div[@class="rental-listing-details"]/h2//a[not(@class)]')
        price = driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, '//div[@class="rental-listing-details"]/h3/strong')
        n_of_bed = driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, '//div[@class="rental-listing-details"]/h3')

        for i in range(len(address)):
            try:
                print(
                    f'{i} {address[i].text} {price[i].text} {n_of_bed[i].text}')

            except IndexError:
                pass

        next = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="pagination"]/li/span[@onclick="GoToPage(' + str(k) + ')"]')
        next.click()

        window_after = driver.window_handles[0]

        driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

        time.sleep(2)

    driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mian()
```

I'd be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no span element exists in that web page with `onclick="GoToPage(5)"` it's `onclick="GoToPage(0 + 1)"`

You can do this,

```
... your code ...

for i in range(len(address)):
    try:
        print(
            f'{i} {address[i].text} {price[i].text} {n_of_bed[i].text}')

    except IndexError:
        pass
if k == 5:
    click_value="GoToPage(0 + 1)" # here is the trcik
else:
    click_value = str(k)
next = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="pagination"]/li/span[@onclick="GoToPage(' + click_value + ')"]')
        next.click()
```